# How to reduce gas from eating beans?

Tags: beans

I have heard a few suggestions for reducing gas (flatulence) from eating beans, including:

- Kombu (seaweed)
- Draining the beans after boiling

Any other thoughts?
How effective either of these.

Comment: The answers here are looking a bit better but this is still a duplicate. I'll merge these questions later.